# How can I use this method in conjunction with another method?

Tags: java, string, methods, symbols

I am trying to finish this code off and get it working, but I cannot figure out why it is not working, the program is using methods to compute a grade from an exam mark input and pring out a pass/fail string. I have been putting the program together well until now, the last method won't function or compile. The copiler says:

```
error: cannot find symbol
   gradeMessage(examGrade);
            ^
```

However, as my program shows, the method is there. So what am I doing wrong? A word of warning, as this is an assessment, the main method must have the four statements only, nothing else.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradeClassifier
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        titleString();
        int examMark = getMark();
        examGrade(examMark);
        gradeMessage(examGrade);
    }

    /**
      Prints title of the program
      @param title the string with dashed underline
    */
    public static void titleString() {
        // Print Title
        System.out.println("Grade Classifier\n****************");
    }

    /**
      Gets the exam mark for the user
      @param getMark from scanner
      @return the mark
    */
    public static int getMark() {
        // Declare and create a Scanner to read input values
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter exam mark :> ");
        int mark = in.nextInt();
        return mark;
    }

    /**
      Determine the grade
      @param mark
      @return string grade
    */
    public static String examGrade(int mark) {
        // Print out grade
        String grade;
        if (mark <= 100 && mark >=70) {
            grade = "A";
        } else if (mark <= 69 && mark >= 60) {
            grade = "B";
        } else if (mark <= 59 && mark >= 50) {
            grade = "C";
        } else if (mark <= 49 && mark >= 40) {
            grade = "D";
        } else {
            grade = "F";
        }
        return grade;
    }

     /**
       Display grade message
       @param result to find pass or fail
     */
     public static void gradeMessage(String result) {
         // Compute if grade leads to pass or fail
         String message;
         if (result == "F") {
             System.out.println("Unfortunately, you have a Grade F, so you have"
                 + " failed this exam");
         } else {
             System.out.println("Congratulations, you are awarded a Grade"
                 + message + " Pass");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: `examGrade(examMark);` returns an int, but you don't assign it to anything, therefor you can't use that int again. You need something like `int grade = examGrade(examMark);`. You would then call your next method using this int like `gradeMessage(grade);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I noticed in your last method `gradeMessage` you create a String variable `message` and try to print it out rather than trying to print out the result parameter passed into your method. For example your last method should look like this:

```
public static void gradeMessage(String result) {
    // Compute if grade leads to pass or fail

    if (result == "F") {
        System.out.println("Unfortunately, you have a Grade F, so you have failed this exam");
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you are awarded a Grade" + result + " Pass");
    }
}
```

Now if you want to use the method in conjunction with one another you would end up with a main method looking like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    titleString();

    int examMark = getMark();

    gradeMessage(examGrade(examMark));
}
```

In this main method we call the `examGrade` method and pass in the parameter `examMark`. The String value returned from the `examGrade` method is then passed into the `gradeMessage` method.